# Trying to iterate over DataFrame created from excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file which I open with pandas and put into a dataframe. It all works well until I try to iterate over a column in the dataframe using a `for` loop. I get either `df does not exist`, or `#iterrows() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I tried adding this line to code from pandas import dataframe and import dataframe as df neither work

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
def getFunc():
    df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
for index, row in df.iterrows(): #this thows exception
    some_list = row{ColName] * some_val
```

Comment: 1. The function `getFunc` is defined but never called.  2. The dataframe exists only in the scope of the function. You can simply delete the function and read the dataframe before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use return:

```
import pandas as pd
def getFunc():
    df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
    return(df)

df1 = getFunc()
for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
    some_list = row{ColName] * some_val
```